# Titanium build 2 applications in 1

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Can I've two Titanium projects and by command line (for example) compile them to be a single application?

Anyone know if that's possible? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Of course not. You can of course, port parts of each application into a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Only one project can be developed in one application. You can combine parts from different projects. But two different project cannot interact with each other.

Comment: How can I combine parts of diferrent projects? Can you give me any references? thaks for the answer ;)

Comment: It's a simple thing, if you prepared POCs in different applications, just combine those in a single one and test it.. give reference to each functionality and try! :)